doxygen can't find another namespace class with using namespace::class
I'm trying to generate some doxygen docs to this project of mine. The problem is the generated doxygen docs doesn't seem to interpret the inherited enum as part of the project, or better: it doesn't link it to the corresponding RoleList enum page, as shown here
.
The related code:
someDefs.h
#include RoleList.h

namespace utils {

using decision_making::RoleList;

typedef struct {
    ...
    RoleList role;
    ...
} RobotTrack;

}


RoleList.h

namespace decision_making {

enum RoleList {
    DEFENDER,
    DUMMY,
    GOALKEEPER,
    STRIKER,
    ...
};

}


The condensed configs on my Doxyfile are as following:
# Doxyfile 1.9.1

PROJECT_NAME           = "Project"
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = ./documentation
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = YES
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_PRIV_VIRTUAL   = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = YES
SORT_MEMBERS_CTORS_1ST = YES
SORT_GROUP_NAMES       = YES
SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME     = YES
INPUT                  = source/core \
                         ./README.md
RECURSIVE              = YES
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = ./README.md
SOURCE_BROWSER         = YES
HTML_DYNAMIC_SECTIONS  = YES
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES

I've already tried to change RoleList to an enum class, and to tweak the EXTRACT_ configurations, but it doesn't seem to work.

Doxygen 1.9.1 is already a bit an older version but it looks like I can see the same problem as well  with the current master version (1.12.0 (b3c28ea6cc7ee2f7ece9c3f7539ca01cc8b36e5f)). probably best is to to file an issue at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues
